# Need to POST json data with OAuth signature

Tags: java, oauth

I have been using signpost so far as the request was GET and there was no problem using signpost so far. But now I need to sign a POST request with OAUth and seems signpost can't do that as the default http method to get the signature is GET.

I also need to post a json body with the POST request.

Any idea would really be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I have got the solution by tweaking signpost code a bit and following http://www.evanjbrunner.info/posts/json-requests-with-httpurlconnection-in-android/